# can't connect to SQL Server 2008 remote DB MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have looked in to one of the solution you provided for unable to connecting to the SQL Server 2008 in mvc4..I followed your answer but even though i am getting error.

```
public class videoDBContext : DbContext
{
      static videoDBContext()
      {
        Database.SetInitializer<videoDBContext>(null);
      }

       public videoDBContext()
       : base("Name=videoDBContext")
       {
       }

       public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VideoMap());
       }
      }
```

domain class

```
     public class Video
     {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
     }
```

Mapping class as

```
     public class VideoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Video>
     {
      public VideoMap()
      {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Description)
                            .IsRequired()
                            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Video");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
       }
}
```

Controller action as

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    using (videoDBContext context = new videoDBContext())
    {
        var list = **context.Videos.ToList();**
    }

    return View();
  }
```

I am getting error near the line:

```
 Line 20:             var s = context.Videos.ToList();
```

`web.config` file is

```
<add name="videoDBContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.xx.csdl|res://*/Models.xx.ssdl|res://*/Models.xx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=xx.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Please provide the solution. where am I going wrong? And sorry if it is silly or making you to inconvenience.

Comment: What is the name of your remote SQL Server (machine), and what is the name of the database you're trying to connect to? Also: which **edition** of SQL Server 2008 are you trying to connect to on that remote server (Web, Standard, Enterprise etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you analyse your connection string, you'll see:

```
connectionString="...provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;
                  initial catalog=xx.mdf;integrated security=True;
```

The "provider" connection string points to a server `servername` (is that correct?) and appears to be trying to reference a `.mdf` file.

You should **not** do this in production! You should reference the database as it exists on the server, using its **logical** database name - don't mess around with `.mdf` files!

So change your connection string to:

```
<add name="videoDBContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.xx.csdl|res://*/Models.xx.ssdl|res://*/Models.xx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=Vedios;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Include the `initial catalog=Vedios;` into the `provider connection string` deep inside the EF connection string.